# How to prevent a bind mounted directory to be overridden by container's data

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, docker-volume

My docker-compose.yml is like below where I have mounted my local dir `code/drupal` to `/var/www/example.com`. My container creates some temporary cache files inside `/var/www/example.com/temp/`. I want to map everything from container to host and host to container i.e in bidirectional but excluding the **temp** dir. Infact I don't want the content of that temp dir should be synchronized with my host machine.

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/example.com

volumes:
  drupal:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/code/drupal
      o: bind
```

Comment: Crazy idea since I don't really know a way to do this with docer compose, you could try `chattr -R +i code/drupal/var/www/example.com/temp` (correct that path as needed), so that'll make the directory immutable on your local machine. Replace +i with -i to undo, and `lsattr` to check attributes

Comment: How come you want to do this out of interest? Are the temp files massive or something?

Comment: Yes the temp files are massive. Infact I am using Drupal. And Drupal creates some static html/css temp files inside example.com/sites/default/files/ for caching purposes

Comment: Okay, I'd play around with `ln` and symlinking too maybe

Comment: So you mean symlink dir inside a container doesn't override the same dir inside host ?

Comment: Pretty much, there might be some weird flags you can use to do that. Redirect the directory to a non-volumed path. Else you may be able to change the path with drupal config?

Comment: Can we use docker volume propagation here ? By the way symbolic links works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad your issue was solved, I'll post that as an answer. Tell me if I should edit it at all because I don't know the precise details of how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symlink from the problem directory to a non-volumed area in your docker container